# How to make this close?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made this window for my site but I'm horrible at Javascript and I don't know how I would make the window close when they click "Ok" or "x". Can you add some javascript to make it closeable? Here's my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/3eap0vus/

```css
.test *,
.test *:after,
.test *:before  { -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important; -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important; box-sizing: content-box !important }

.test {
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 1001;
}

.test,
.test .test_Title,
.test .test_Body,
.test .test_Buttons a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
}

.test .test_Title,
.test .test_BodyOuter,
.test .test_ButtonsOuter {
    border-color: #13252F;
    border-width: 7px;
}

.test .test_Title {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #F6F5F5;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    background: #444444;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.test .test_BodyOuter {
    background: #E7EDEF;
}

.test .test_Body {
    color: #44484A;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top-color: #000;
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}

.test .test_ButtonsOuter {
    background: #E7EDEF;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 10px;
}

.test .test_Buttons:before,
.test .test_Buttons:after     { content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; visibility: hidden; font-size: 0 }
.test .test_Buttons:after     { clear: both }
.test .test_Buttons           { *zoom: 1 }

.test .test_Buttons a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 2px #222;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.test .test_Buttons a:hover {
    background: #224467;
    color: #FFF
}

.test a.test_Close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    top: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #666
}

.test a.test_Close:hover {
}

.test .test_Title a.test_Close {
    color: #E7EDEF;
}

.test .test_Title a.test_Close:hover {
}

.testOverlay {
    background: #666;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.test {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.test .test_Title {
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.test .test_BodyOuter {
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
}

.test .test_NoTitle {
    border-top-style: solid;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.test .test_NoButtons {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.test .test_Body {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-style: groove;
    overflow: auto;
}

.test .test_NoTitle .test_Body {
    border-top: none;
}

.test .test_NoButtons .test_Body {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.test .test_Icon {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 20px 20px;
    padding-left: 88px;
    min-height: 48px;
    _height: 85px;
}

.test .test_Confirmation  { background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b792cc6d45.png') }
.test .test_Error         { background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b78fb8bcdb.png') }
.test .test_Information   { background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b79592c464.png') }
.test .test_Question      { background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b797dc528f.png') }
.test .test_Warning       { background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b79a3e68af.png') }

.test .test_ButtonsOuter {
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.test .test_Buttons a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    min-width: 60px;
    float: right;
    _width: 60px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;

    background-color: #006DCC;
    *background-color: #0044CC;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088CC, #0044CC);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088CC), to(#0044CC));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088CC, #0044CC);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088CC, #0044CC);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088CC, #0044CC);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: #0044CC #0044CC #002A80;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FF0088CC', endColorstr='#FF0044CC', GradientType=0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}

.test .test_Buttons_Centered .test_Buttons {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.test .test_Buttons_Centered a {
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="testOverlay" style="position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; opacity: 0.9;"></div><div class="test" style="position: fixed; left: 433px; top: 223px; visibility: visible; width: 500px; opacity: 1;"><h3 class="test_Title">Information<a href="" class="test_Close" style="right: 15px; top: 9.5px;">×</a></h3><div class="test_BodyOuter"><div class="test_Body test_Icon test_Information"><div style="padding-top: 14px;"><strong>Test<br></strong></div></div></div><div class="test_ButtonsOuter"><div class="test_Buttons"><a href="" class="test_Button_0">Ok</a></div></div></div>
```

Comment: You want to remove it on click or hide it?

Comment: @ZeevKatz I want the window to be hidden when the user clicks "Ok" or "x" and if it's not too much to ask can you make it so when they click "Ok" or "x" that the user doesn't see it on reload

Comment: If you dont know js and php at all its very problem for explanation. Ill write for you a simple example and try to use it.

Comment: I kinda know php but I'm a beginner at it

Comment: With your question you are asking someone to do your job for you. You don't show any attempt in fixing the problem yourself. If you have tried to make it close with javascript, show what you tried and what went wrong first. If you don't know how to program JS at all, do a google search. A quick search on google for instance turned up this result: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added css

```
.test{
top:0px !important;
left:0px !important;
}
```

So that the window can show in properly. You can take this out if needed

see snippet

```js
function close() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByClassName('testOverlay')[0].style.display = "none";
}

document.getElementsByClassName('test_Close')[0].addEventListener('click', close)
document.getElementsByClassName(test_Button_0 ')[0].addEventListener('
    click ',close)
```

```css
.test *,
.test *:after,
.test *:before {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
  box-sizing: content-box !important
}
.test {
  width: 350px;
  z-index: 1001;
}
.test,
.test .test_Title,
.test .test_Body,
.test .test_Buttons a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
}
.test .test_Title,
.test .test_BodyOuter,
.test .test_ButtonsOuter {
  border-color: #13252F;
  border-width: 7px;
}
.test .test_Title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F6F5F5;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background: #444444;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.test .test_BodyOuter {
  background: #E7EDEF;
}
.test .test_Body {
  color: #44484A;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top-color: #000;
  border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}
.test .test_ButtonsOuter {
  background: #E7EDEF;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 10px;
}
.test .test_Buttons:before,
.test .test_Buttons:after {
  content: "\0020";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0
}
.test .test_Buttons:after {
  clear: both
}
.test .test_Buttons {
  *zoom: 1
}
.test .test_Buttons a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 1px 0px 2px #222;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.test .test_Buttons a:hover {
  background: #224467;
  color: #FFF
}
.test a.test_Close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #666
}
.test a.test_Close:hover {} .test .test_Title a.test_Close {
  color: #E7EDEF;
}
.test .test_Title a.test_Close:hover {} .testOverlay {
  background: #666;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.test {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.test .test_Title {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.test .test_BodyOuter {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
}
.test .test_NoTitle {
  border-top-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.test .test_NoButtons {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.test .test_Body {
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-style: groove;
  overflow: auto;
}
.test .test_NoTitle .test_Body {
  border-top: none;
}
.test .test_NoButtons .test_Body {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.test .test_Icon {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 20px 20px;
  padding-left: 88px;
  min-height: 48px;
  _height: 85px;
}
.test .test_Confirmation {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b792cc6d45.png')
}
.test .test_Error {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b78fb8bcdb.png')
}
.test .test_Information {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b79592c464.png')
}
.test .test_Question {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b797dc528f.png')
}
.test .test_Warning {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b79a3e68af.png')
}
.test .test_ButtonsOuter {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.test .test_Buttons a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  min-width: 60px;
  float: right;
  _width: 60px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #006DCC;
  *background-color: #0044CC;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088CC, #0044CC);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088CC), to(#0044CC));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088CC, #0044CC);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088CC, #0044CC);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088CC, #0044CC);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #0044CC #0044CC #002A80;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FF0088CC', endColorstr='#FF0044CC', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}
.test .test_Buttons_Centered .test_Buttons {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.test .test_Buttons_Centered a {
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.test {
  top: 0px !important;
  left: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="testOverlay" style="position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; opacity: 0.9;"></div>
<div class="test" style="position: fixed; left: 433px; top: 223px; visibility: visible; width: 500px; opacity: 1;">
  <h3 class="test_Title">Information<a href="" class="test_Close" style="right: 15px; top: 9.5px;">×</a></h3>
  <div class="test_BodyOuter">
    <div class="test_Body test_Icon test_Information">
      <div style="padding-top: 14px;"><strong>Test<br></strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test_ButtonsOuter">
    <div class="test_Buttons"><a href="" class="test_Button_0">Ok</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This snippet is much more better

```js
function close() {
  console.log('close')
  document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByClassName('testOverlay')[0].style.display = "none";
}

function show() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].style.display = "block";
  document.getElementsByClassName('testOverlay')[0].style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementsByClassName('test_Close')[0].addEventListener('click', close);
document.getElementsByClassName('test_Button_0')[0].addEventListener('click', close)

document.getElementById("press").addEventListener('click', show)
```

```css
.test *,
.test *:after,
.test *:before {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
  box-sizing: content-box !important
}
.test {
  width: 350px;
  z-index: 1001;
}
.test,
.test .test_Title,
.test .test_Body,
.test .test_Buttons div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
}
.test .test_Title,
.test .test_BodyOuter,
.test .test_ButtonsOuter {
  border-color: #13252F;
  border-width: 7px;
}
.test .test_Title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F6F5F5;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background: #444444;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.test .test_BodyOuter {
  background: #E7EDEF;
}
.test .test_Body {
  color: #44484A;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top-color: #000;
  border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}
.test .test_ButtonsOuter {
  background: #E7EDEF;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 10px;
}
.test .test_Buttons:before,
.test .test_Buttons:after {
  content: "\0020";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0
}
.test .test_Buttons:after {
  clear: both
}
.test .test_Buttons {
  *zoom: 1
}
.test .test_Buttons div {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 1px 0px 2px #222;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.test .test_Buttons div:hover {
  background: #224467;
  color: #FFF
}
.test div.test_Close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #666
}
.test div.test_Close:hover {} .test .test_Title a.test_Close {
  color: #E7EDEF;
}
.test .test_Title a.test_Close:hover {} .testOverlay {
  background: #666;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.test {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.test .test_Title {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.test .test_BodyOuter {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
}
.test {} .test .test_NoTitle {
  border-top-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.test .test_NoButtons {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.test .test_Body {
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-style: groove;
  overflow: auto;
}
.test .test_NoTitle .test_Body {
  border-top: none;
}
.test .test_NoButtons .test_Body {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.test .test_Icon {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 20px 20px;
  padding-left: 88px;
  min-height: 48px;
  _height: 85px;
}
.test .test_Confirmation {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b792cc6d45.png')
}
.test .test_Error {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b78fb8bcdb.png')
}
.test .test_Information {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b79592c464.png')
}
.test .test_Question {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b797dc528f.png')
}
.test .test_Warning {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b79a3e68af.png')
}
.test .test_ButtonsOuter {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.test .test_Buttons div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  min-width: 60px;
  float: right;
  _width: 60px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #006DCC;
  *background-color: #0044CC;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088CC, #0044CC);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088CC), to(#0044CC));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088CC, #0044CC);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088CC, #0044CC);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088CC, #0044CC);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #0044CC #0044CC #002A80;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FF0088CC', endColorstr='#FF0044CC', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}
.test .test_Buttons_Centered .test_Buttons {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.test .test_Buttons_Centered {
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.test {
  top: 0px !important;
  left: 0px !important;
}
.test,
.test_Close {
  display: inline-block;
}
.test:hover,
.test_Close:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}
.test,
.testOverlay {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="press">
  Press
</button>
<div class="testOverlay" style="position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; opacity: 0.9;"></div>
<div class="test" style="position: fixed; left: 433px; top: 223px; visibility: visible; width: 500px; opacity: 1;">
  <h3 class="test_Title">Information<div href="" class="test_Close" style="right: 15px; top: 9.5px;">×</div></h3>
  <div class="test_BodyOuter">
    <div class="test_Body test_Icon test_Information">
      <div style="padding-top: 14px;"><strong>Test<br></strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test_ButtonsOuter">
    <div class="test_Buttons">
      <div class="test_Button_0">Ok</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks, but one question. Will the box be there if the user reloads the page?

Comment: Yes If the page is reloaded everything is reloaded with it....also I just set the display property to **none** so the box is hidden

Comment: You mean clicking reload page?

Comment: Can you make it so when the user clicks "Ok" or "x" that on reload that the user can't see it? I'm sory if this is too much to ask

Comment: You would like to hide it everytime the window loads and when you press a button or something it shows?

Comment: sorry about that...I am here...hmm.....okay.. I don't think you should use those anchor tags they seem to redirect...use div.. I am editing answer to show you a better way with snippet 2

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's counter-intuitive, but while in the UI you think of this as a "window" to be "closed", what you have is just a DIV like any other, but with special stylesheet settings to act like a window.  So instead of worry about closing it, you just need to hide it when the user clicks the X or whatever.

(If you *really* want to, you could actually remove the DIV from the page's DOM, but I know of no reason to do that.)

How exactly to do that depends on some things - like jQuery or raw javascript, and does it matter whether the "closed window" would still occupy layout space.  (You've shown a lot of css, so apologies but I don't have time just now to dig through it all and fully understand your layout.)

But hopefully it points you in the right direction to know that you need to get the element for the window's DIV ($(".testOverlay") if you're using jQuery) and then apply a style of either `display: none` or `visibility:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Talking about pure Javascript, looks like you want something like this..

You can run it:

```js
// Waiting DOM load
window.onload = function() {
  // Binding event click to the close button, and defining it's callback
  document.querySelector(".test_Close").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // Prevent the click in <a> to redirect the page to itself or another place
    e.preventDefault();
    // Closing the overlay
    document.querySelector(".testOverlay").style.display = "none";
    // Closing the modal
    document.querySelector(".test").style.display = "none";
    // Check your browser console with F12 or Ctrl + Shift + I
    console.info("Modal has been closed!");
  });
}
```

```css
.test *,
.test *:after,
.test *:before {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
  box-sizing: content-box !important
}
.test {
  width: 350px;
  z-index: 1001;
}
.test,
.test .test_Title,
.test .test_Body,
.test .test_Buttons a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
}
.test .test_Title,
.test .test_BodyOuter,
.test .test_ButtonsOuter {
  border-color: #13252F;
  border-width: 7px;
}
.test .test_Title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F6F5F5;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background: #444444;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.test .test_BodyOuter {
  background: #E7EDEF;
}
.test .test_Body {
  color: #44484A;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top-color: #000;
  border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}
.test .test_ButtonsOuter {
  background: #E7EDEF;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 10px;
}
.test .test_Buttons:before,
.test .test_Buttons:after {
  content: "\0020";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0
}
.test .test_Buttons:after {
  clear: both
}
.test .test_Buttons {
  *zoom: 1
}
.test .test_Buttons a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 1px 0px 2px #222;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.test .test_Buttons a:hover {
  background: #224467;
  color: #FFF
}
.test a.test_Close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #666
}
.test a.test_Close:hover {} .test .test_Title a.test_Close {
  color: #E7EDEF;
}
.test .test_Title a.test_Close:hover {} .testOverlay {
  background: #666;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.test {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.test .test_Title {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.test .test_BodyOuter {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
}
.test .test_NoTitle {
  border-top-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.test .test_NoButtons {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.test .test_Body {
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-style: groove;
  overflow: auto;
}
.test .test_NoTitle .test_Body {
  border-top: none;
}
.test .test_NoButtons .test_Body {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.test .test_Icon {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 20px 20px;
  padding-left: 88px;
  min-height: 48px;
  _height: 85px;
}
.test .test_Confirmation {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b792cc6d45.png')
}
.test .test_Error {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b78fb8bcdb.png')
}
.test .test_Information {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b79592c464.png')
}
.test .test_Question {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b797dc528f.png')
}
.test .test_Warning {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/b79a3e68af.png')
}
.test .test_ButtonsOuter {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.test .test_Buttons a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  min-width: 60px;
  float: right;
  _width: 60px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #006DCC;
  *background-color: #0044CC;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088CC, #0044CC);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088CC), to(#0044CC));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088CC, #0044CC);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088CC, #0044CC);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088CC, #0044CC);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #0044CC #0044CC #002A80;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FF0088CC', endColorstr='#FF0044CC', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}
.test .test_Buttons_Centered .test_Buttons {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.test .test_Buttons_Centered a {
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.test {
  top: 0px !important;
  left: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="testOverlay" style="position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; opacity: 0.9;"></div>
<div class="test" style="position: fixed; left: 433px; top: 223px; visibility: visible; width: 500px; opacity: 1;">

  <!-- Have set void(0), that evaluates the given expression and then returns undefined -->
  <h3 class="test_Title">Information<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="test_Close" style="right: 15px; top: 9.5px;">×</a></h3>

  <div class="test_BodyOuter">
    <div class="test_Body test_Icon test_Information">
      <div style="padding-top: 14px;"><strong>Test<br></strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test_ButtonsOuter">
    <div class="test_Buttons"><a href="" class="test_Button_0">Ok</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps you.